# Axios Header Globally Not Working After Login Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

i have a problem with axios login with Vue 3.

After access API login and auth successfully, i put router.push to redirect page to dashboard, the code like this:

```
            axios.post('auth/signin', {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }).then((response) => {
                localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.data.accessToken)
                localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', response.data.refreshToken)

                toast.success("Login sukses")

                if(VueJwtDecode.decode(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')).sub == "admin"){
                    router.push({name: 'admin.dashboard.index'})
                }else if(VueJwtDecode.decode(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')).sub == "user"){
                    router.push({name: 'user.dashboard.index'})
                }else if(VueJwtDecode.decode(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')).sub == "company"){
                    router.push({name: 'company.dashboard.index'})
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                toast.error(error.response.data.error.message);
            })
```

Its successfully redirect user to dashboard, but the axios header is not working, i must refresh (f5) the browser page to make axios header start function.

even though I have already add

```
axios.defaults.headers['x-access-token'] = localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
```

line at main.js

How to fix that? Thanks before.

Comment: Why not add `axios.defaults.headers['x-access-token'] = response.data.accessToken` just  after login?

Comment: Its only work once, after i refresh the browser, its will not work

Comment: I'm not suggesting to remove the entry from `main.js`

Comment: okay, its work now. I dont remove entry from main js, and also add it after login. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`main.js` will only get compiled at first boot so you should edit your `axios` header when the new access token arrived

Comment: @ASHafizullah You are welcome, please consider to mark my answer as the correct answer if it helped you